# How to redirect this form to subdirectory php/handler.php

Tags: php, html

and thanks for previous help! I am almost where I want to be.

I have been trying to get a form which sends an accompanying file working. I just managed it. I just want to tidy up a bit.

I got the form and all that comes with it from [here](http://reusableforms.com/d/e2/bootstrap-contact-form-with-validation).

It comes with a lot of bewildering stuff. It has PHPMailer and composer. I uploaded it to my webpage in the /home/mywebpage/public_html/php directory, as it is php. There are now a lot of sub-directories and many many things I do not understand.

The above link gives me a formpage.html page.

When I open this page from www.mywebpage.com/php/formpage.html I can send data and a file to an email address I specify in handler.php

I get a nice email with the contact form data in the email and an email attachment, my file.

You can view formpage.html and all of these files from the link above.

I am a raw beginner with this stuff. When I send data to myself, the

```
<form action="php/thankyou18BEweek15.php" method="POST" name="myForm" onsubmit="return checkForExpiration();" >
```

because I keep all php stuff in the subfolder /php. That way, my php thankyou file is found.

The formpage html

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form">
```

I don’t see any `<form action=“handler.php”` or a file with the name "form" so I am not sure how to alter this.

How can I alter this to make it drop a directory (it is in public_html), drop to php/ and find all the php and PHPMailer stuff?

I think I should put formpage.html in /home/mywebpage/public_html and I want to leave all the other stuff in /php

How to redirect the `<form>` from public_html to php?

[This](https://riptutorial.com/html/example/9155/role--form-) comes apparently from stackoverflow and has the nasty words " (not recommended, invalid)"

Comment: _“I don’t see any <form action=“handler.php” […] so I am not sure how to alter this.”_ - a form without an action attribute set, or an empty one, simply points back to the current URL. If you want it to sends its data elsewhere - then _add_ an `action` attribute …

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.  At one point you seem to say that your form is working, and then at another you seem to say that it isn't.  Which is it?  Do you have two _different_ forms where one is working and one isn't?  There's a lot of words here, but few of them are helpful, and there's even less code.

Comment: @Patrick: The form works from the subfolder php. I think the formpage.html should be in the folder public_html When I put it there, it does not work. I added action=‘php/handler.php’ and changed a line in form.js to url: $form.attr('action'), now it works, but the success message does not display correctly. However, the form data + file get sent! I'll work on it! If only it was not so complicated! I cannot see how it works, but it works!